# Using Linq to sum up to a number (and skip the rest)

Tags: c#, linq

If we have a class that contains a number like this:

```
class Person 
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int Amount {get; set;}
}
```

and then a collection of people:

```
IList<Person> people;
```

That contains, let's say 10 people of random names and amounts
is there a Linq expression that will return me a subcollection of Person objects whose sum fulfills a condition?

For example I want the first x people whose sum of Amount is under 1000.
I can do that traditionally by

```
 var subgroup = new List<Person>();

 people.OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount);

 var count = 0;
 foreach (var person in people)
 {
    count += person.Amount;
    if (count < requestedAmount)
    {
        subgroup.Add(person);
    }
    else  
    {
        break;
    }
 }
```

But i've been wondering if there's an elegant Linq way of doing something like this using Sum and then some other function like Take?

### UPDATE

This is fantastic:

```
var count = 0;
var subgroup = people
                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount)
                  .TakeWhile(x => (count += x.Amount) < requestedAmount)
                  .ToList();
```

But I am wondering if I can somehow change it further in order to grab the next person in the people list and add the remainder into the sum so that the total amount equals requested amount.

Comment: `people.OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount);` this line, doesn't do anything _(usefull)_, because the returned value will become sorted, not the list itself...

Comment: I understand, but I wrote this as pseudocode. Sorry if it wasn't clear

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `TakeWhile`:

```
int s = 0;
var subgroup  = people.OrderBy(x => x.Amount)
                      .TakeWhile(x => (s += x.Amount) < 1000)
                      .ToList();
```

**Note:** You mention in your post *first* x people. One could interpret this as the ones having the smallest amount that adds up until `1000` is reached. So, I used `OrderBy`. But you can substitute this with `OrderByDescending` if you want to start fetching from the person having the highest amount.

---

**Edit:**

To make it select *one more* item from the list you can use:

```
.TakeWhile(x => {
                   bool bExceeds = s > 1000;
                   s += x.Amount;                                 
                   return !bExceeds;
                })
```

The `TakeWhile` here examines the `s` value from the *previous* iteration, so it will take one more, just to be sure `1000` has been exceeded.

Comment: Nice answer, I think `TakeWhile` is better than `Where`, because it will stop iterating.  Same results, but better for iteration. You got my vote.

Comment: Well this is fantastic... but just to spice it up a bit, is there a way to take from the next person the remainder value so that the average sum will equal "requestedAmount"?

Comment: @Nick Slightly ugly but; `x => (s += x.Amount) < 1000||(done^=true)`

Comment: Please don't modify variables in LINQ queries; it's a really bad programming practice. It can lead to some truly bizarre scenarios.

Comment: @EricLippert I agree, when the subgroup is iterated more than ones, it will give strange results, because the counter isn't resetted. I added another answer with an extension method that does the trick.

Answer (score 24):

I don't like these approaches of mutating state inside linq queries.

EDIT: 
I did not state that the my previous code was untested and was somewhat pseudo-y. I also missed the point that Aggregate actually eats the entire thing at once - as correctly pointed out it didn't work. The idea was right though, but we need an alternative to Aggreage.

It's a shame that LINQ don't have a running aggregate. I suggest the code from user2088029 in this post: [How to compute a running sum of a series of ints in a Linq query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184812/how-to-compute-a-running-sum-of-a-series-of-ints-in-a-linq-query).

And then use this (which is tested and is what I intended):

```
var y = people.Scanl(new { item = (Person) null, Amount = 0 },
    (sofar, next) => new { 
        item = next, 
        Amount = sofar.Amount + next.Amount 
    } 
);
```

Stolen code here for longevity:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Scanl<T, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    TResult first,
    Func<TResult, T, TResult> combine)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> data = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            yield return first;

            while (data.MoveNext())
            {
                first = combine(first, data.Current);
                yield return first;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Previous, wrong code:

I have another suggestion; begin with a list

```
people

[{"a", 100}, 
 {"b", 200}, 
 ... ]
```

Calculate the running totals:

```
people.Aggregate((sofar, next) => new {item = next, total = sofar.total + next.value})


[{item: {"a", 100}, total: 100}, 
 {item: {"b", 200}, total: 300},
 ... ]
```

Then use TakeWhile and Select to return to just items;

```
people
 .Aggregate((sofar, next) => new {item = next, total = sofar.total + next.value})
 .TakeWhile(x=>x.total<1000)
 .Select(x=>x.Item)
```

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: You are absolutely right. I made some assumptions that were wrong - please check the updated code.

Comment: @NiklasJ Great you updated your answer, **funny to see all the sheeps clicking without checking**....  _(based on your/eric's idea I wrote an extension method (see my seconden answer))_

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen The upside of Scanl is that it's generic and reusable for any even vaguely similar situation. It's a missing function from LINQ, basically. While there isn't anything wrong with your code, in my point of view it's a procedural solution to the problem.

Comment: It think, the code you provided is less readable than my `TakeWhileAdding` extension method. As you can see how the method is called. I don't see a problem by creating some overload methods for each type used. _(int, float, double, TimeSpan, etc)_

Comment: This is turning into chat. I'm heavily influenced by Clojure, where this pair of function is called reduce/reductions. Linq could have (and imo should have) Aggregate/Aggregates. Assuming that did exist, I think an inline procedural solution is a worse option than a combination of standard tools. The only thing added here is the missing function. I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 17):

I dislike all answers to this question. They either mutate a variable in a query -- a bad practice that leads to unexpected results -- or in the case of Niklas's (otherwise good) solution, returns a sequence that is of the wrong type, or, in the case of Jeroen's answer, the code is correct but could be made to solve a more general problem.

I would improve the efforts of Niklas and Jeroen by making an actually generic solution that returns the right type:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AggregatingTakeWhile<T, U>(
  this IEnumerable<T> items, 
  U first,
  Func<T, U, U> aggregator,
  Func<T, U, bool> predicate)
{
  U aggregate = first;
  foreach (var item in items)
  {
    aggregate = aggregator(item, aggregate);
    if (!predicate(item, aggregate))
      yield break;
    yield return item; 
  }
}
```

Which we can now use to implement a solution to the specific problem:

```
var subgroup = people
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount)
  .AggregatingTakeWhile(
    0, 
    (item, count) => count + item.Amount, 
    (item, count) => count < requestedAmount)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
int sumCount = 0;

var subgroup = people
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Amount)           // <-- you wanted to sort them?
    .Where(item => (sumCount += item.Amount) < requestedAmount)
    .ToList();
```

But it's not charming... It will be less readable.

Answer (score 3):

I took the comment of `Eric Lippert` and came with this *better* solution. I think the best way is to create a function *(in my case I wrote an Extension Method)*

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeWhileAdding<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, 
    Func<T, int> selector, 
    Func<int, bool> comparer)
{
    int total = 0;

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        total += selector(item);

        if (!comparer(total))
            yield break;

        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var values = new Person[]
{
    new Person { Name = "Name1", Amount = 300 },
    new Person { Name = "Name2", Amount = 500 },
    new Person { Name = "Name3", Amount = 300 },
    new Person { Name = "Name4", Amount = 300 }
};

var subgroup = values.TakeWhileAdding(
    person => person.Amount, 
    total => total < requestedAmount);

foreach (var v in subgroup)
    Trace.WriteLine(v);
```

This could also be created for `double`, `float`, or something like a `TimeSpan`.

This way each time the `subgroup` is iterated, a new counter is used.

Answer (score 1):

Giorgos pointed me to the right direction so his answer is the accepted one.

However for completeness I am writing here the solution that I ended up with.

```
var count = 0;
var exceeds = false;

var subgroup  = people.OrderBy(x => x.Amount).TakeWhile(x =>
{
    if (exceeds)
    {
        return false;
    }

    count += x.Amount;
    if (count >= requestedAmount)
    {
        x.Amount = requestedAmount - (count - x.Amount);
        exceeds = true;
        return true;
    }

    return !exceeds;
}).ToList();
```

This returns a subgroup whose total amount is equal to the requested amount.
Thanks so much!

Comment: `return !exceeds` should be `return true` since `exceeds` can only be `false`  at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using Nicks answer in combination with an ORM, since it can change the objects value in the database too when wrapping a transaction around it, either purposefully or not. At least that is the case in our company. It has served us well though.